# How to parse HTML sub tags in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, tags, html-parser

I have HTML webpage with lot of images and live contents. I need to `parse the data from the webpage(HTML)` and show in the iPhone app. Am using the following code to parse the HTML content. But i don't know how to parse the sub tags in the  tags?

```
{    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.samplewebpage.com/vd/t/1/830.html"]; 

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response : %@", responseString);

    NSMutableArray *imageURLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *divClassArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NSString *regexStr = @"<A HREF=\"([^>]*)\">";

    // For image : 1. img src=\"([^>]*)\"  2. <img src=\"([^>]*)\">
    // For getting Class div class
    NSString *regularExpressString = @"div class=\"([^>]*)\"";
    NSError *error;
    NSInteger i =0;
    while (i<[responseString length]) 
    {
        NSRegularExpression *testRegularExpress = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regularExpressString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

        if( testRegularExpress == nil ) 
        {
            NSLog( @"Error making regex: %@", error );
        }

        NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult = [testRegularExpress firstMatchInString:responseString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(i, [responseString length]-i)];
        NSRange range = [textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1];
        if (range.location == 0) 
        { 
            break;
        }
        NSString *classNameString = [responseString substringWithRange:range];
        NSLog(@"Div Class Name : %@", classNameString);

        [divClassArray addObject:classNameString];

        i= range.location;
        //NSLog(@"Range.location : %i",range.location);
        i=i+range.length;
    }

    NSLog(@"divClass Array : %@, Count : %d", divClassArray, [divClassArray count]);
}
```

Response:

```
<div class="phoneModelItems" style="width:30%;margin-right:4px;"><a href="javascript:noxLatestChart.navToLatestChart('latest');" style="font-weight:italic;">Nokia Model</a></div>
```

I want to get the text **Nokia Model** from the class **phoneModelItems**. Can you please tell me how to retrieve the text 'Nokia Model'?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the responseString

Comment: Mr.Meccan thanks for your response. I have edited the question. I have already mentioned the response. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Regular Expression for your problem:

```
<div\sclass=\"phoneModelItems\".*?><a\shref.*?>(.*?)<\/a><\/div>
```

you can test it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/q3KhDqNdVI)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Meccan. I will try in my project. Thanks once again.